# How can add special property to a column of table without defining a new column type

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

How can I add special property to a column of table, **without** defining a new column type?
Because, maybe I use that **one time** in all of my book, for example, I want to change color of column 1 of a table in my book.

Comment: How is that related to `tcolorbox` which you used as a tag for your question?

Comment: `>{\color{red}}l` for example produces a left aligned column whose contents are written in red. (Requires the `xcolor` and `array` packages.)